# Bind to Existing Process

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to open SQL Server Management studio,programitically, i have used **Process** to open SQL Server  and have used Start() Method to open the process,

```
                    using System.Diagnostics;
                    Process Sql = new Process();
                    string strfile1="example1.sql";
                    string strfile2="example2.sql";
                    Sql.StartInfo.FileName = "Ssms.exe";//sql server process
                    Sql.StartInfo.Arguments = strfile1;
                    Sql.Start();
                    Sql.StartInfo.Arguments = strfile2;
                    Sql.Start();
```

This code opens two instance of SQL server,but I want to check if the process is already running and reuse the existing process and open the  example2.sql in the same Process.How can this be done ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a process is running by name (you need to find out the name of your ssms process) like this:

```
Process[] procName= Process.GetProcessesByName("INSERT NAME HERE");
if (procName.Length >= 0)
{
  //you are already running
}
```

but I don't think you'll be able to then modify an existing instance of ssms.

Answer (score 1):

What if you let the OS decide what to do?

```
Process.Start("example1.sql");
Process.Start("example2.sql");
```